# to find the IntegrationServiceVersionState of the VM's present in hyper V code using wmi object in c++

Tags: c++, wmi

Iam trying to find the IntegrationServiceVersionState of the VM's present in hyper V code using wmi object in c++

IntegrationServiceVersionState  can be accessed by calling  GetSummaryInformation method of the Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService class present in root\virtualization\v2 namespace

the snippet of code am facing error is

```
// Set up to call the Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService::GetSummaryInformation method
BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService");
BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"GetSummaryInformation");

cout << "setup initialised" << endl;

//get class

IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
hr = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);

cout << "class object got" << endl;
GetWMIError(hr);



//to get the path of the class
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator1 = NULL;
hr = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    BSTR(L"WQL"),
    BSTR(L"select * from MSVM_VirtualSystemManagementService "),/*where Caption=\"Virtual Machine\"*/
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator1);

IWbemClassObject* pVirtualSystemManagementServiceObj = NULL;
ULONG uReturn1 = 0;
hr = pEnumerator1->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pVirtualSystemManagementServiceObj, &uReturn1);

if (uReturn1 == 0)
{
    cout << " couldnt load class path " << endl;
}
VARIANT classpath;
hr = pVirtualSystemManagementServiceObj->Get(L"__Path", 0, &classpath, 0, 0);
wcout << " __Path : " << classpath.bstrVal << endl;


// Get Method

IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
hr = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);
cout << "method object got" << endl;
GetWMIError(hr);


// get spawn instance

IWbemClassObject* pClassInstance = NULL;
hr = pInParamsDefinition->SpawnInstance(0, &pClassInstance);
cout << "SpAwn instanaaace e" << endl;
GetWMIError(hr);


//setting data
VARIANT SetData ;
VariantInit(&SetData);
SetData.vt = VT_NULL;
hr = pClassInstance->Put(L"SettingData", 0, &SetData, 0);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "failed to load setting data parameter" << endl;
}

GetWMIError(hr);
cout << "1st parameter set" << endl;



//requested information 
VARIANT reqInfo;
VariantInit(&reqInfo);

SAFEARRAY *psa;
SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
rgsabound[0].cElements = 2;

CComSafeArray<int> arr(5);
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 123;

long nIndex = 0;

psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_I4, 1, rgsabound);
hr = SafeArrayPutElement(psa, &nIndex, &arr[0]);
nIndex++;
SafeArrayPutElement(psa, &nIndex, &arr[1]);

reqInfo.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_I4;
reqInfo.parray = psa;

hr = pClassInstance->Put(L"RequestedInformation", 0, &reqInfo, 0);


GetWMIError(hr);
cout << "2nd parameter set" << endl;



//execute method

IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
hr = pSvc->ExecMethod(classpath.bstrVal, MethodName, 0, NULL, pClassInstance, &pOutParams, NULL);
GetWMIError(hr);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    cout << "Could not execute method. Error code = 0x" << hex << hr << endl;
}
GetWMIError(hr);
cout << "method executed" << endl;
```

the above code works properly but am facing problem in  the below code

```
VARIANT varReturnValue;
VariantInit(&varReturnValue);
hr = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"ReturnValue"), 0,&varReturnValue, NULL, 0);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{   
    if (varReturnValue.vt == VT_I4)
    {
        CIMTYPE ct;
        VARIANT varJob;
        VariantInit(&varJob);
        hr = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"SummaryInformation"), 0, &varJob, &ct, 0);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (varJob.vt == VT_ARRAY | VT_UNKNOWN)
            {
                VARIANT myvar;  
                myvar.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_UNKNOWN;
                SAFEARRAY* pSafeArray = V_ARRAY(&myvar);

                long lBound, uBound;
                SafeArrayGetLBound(pSafeArray, 1, &lBound);
                SafeArrayGetUBound(pSafeArray, 1, &uBound);
                cout << lBound << endl;
                cout << uBound << endl;

                UINT16 Element = NULL;
                for (long i = lBound; i <= uBound; i++)
                {
                    hr = SafeArrayGetElement(pSafeArray, &i, &Element);
                    wcout << Element << endl;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got the number of VM's correctly, but facing error in getting the array elements. It just throws some garbage values.
Please some one help to rectify this issue